# How to read the Foreigner Universe

Tags: suggested-order, foreigner-series

I have read the first trilogy in C.J. Cherryh's *Foreigner* universe and found them to be excellent. It's been a while, though, so I'm re-reading them.

I've also discovered that there are actually *four* trilogies, with a fifth currently in progress. I've also learned that the timelines for each trilogy overlap, although the story arc for each trilogy stands on its own.

Is there a "canonical" order for reading these? Is simply reading them in the published order the best way to do it, or will I get more out of them by reading them in an alternative order? (For instance: "read book 1 of trilogy 3 before reading book 3 of trilogy 2.")

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Published order is definitely the way to go. There's no messing around with internal chronology -- each book follows on from the previous one. You'll get pretty lost if you try to read them in any other order.

I think your count of trilogies is off by one, though. Three trilogies have been completed, and a fourth is in progress.

Comment: Thanks for that. (I got my information from here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreigner_universe#Story_arcs)

Comment: Ah, we're using different definitions of "in progress" and "completed". From C J Cherryh's point of view, the fourth trilogy is complete and she's working on the fifth. But the last book in the fourth trilogy has not yet been published.

Comment: Well, it'll be out LONG before I can get to it, so that works for me.